# Android Media Notification creates a new task when first clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have been developing an app that plays media with exoplayer. Currently I have a `PlayerActivity` that can be launched from different places of the app and an `AudioPlayerService` that is created to play the music in the background with a media notification.  Everything is good so far.

What I basically want is when user pressed the home button and then pressed on the notification, it should open up the existing `PlayerActivity` which is already on top of the current activity stack. I have the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` set in the manifest.

I have the `createCurrentContentIntent` method for creating PendingIntent as below:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.SUBVERSION_PARAM, subversion);
            intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.SESSION_PARAM, session);
            intent.putExtra(MUSIC_PARAM, musicItem);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }else{
                return PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }
```

The problem is that when I clicked on the notification it creates a new task (which is shown as a separate task on the Recents as well.) and so creates a new instance of the `PlayerActivity`. Now that I have two separate tasks of the activity, if I go back home and click the notification again, it just triggers the `onNewIntent` on the new created activity and goes on as expected since it is set to `singleTop`.

I have been reading through many questions around but could not manage to solve the problem. Am I missing something ? How can I make the notification to trigger the activity in the first task and work as expected from the beginning ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem: there was an accidental `taskAffinity` value set in my manifest file for the splash activity and it was somehow causing the notification to create a new task in the first time.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve this. You can accept your answer which will remove the question from the list of open questions and might help someone else with a similar problem.